# What is viewRoot in QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I found a QML file with the following:

```
Page {
    id: viewRoot
    ...
}
```

and I thought it was something defined in the project itself but I couldn't find. Then I searched github for code containing the variable `viewRoot` and found a lot of them using this same thing: `id: viewRoot`.

What is `viewRoot` and how can I write the same code in the pure C++ version of my QML object I'm creating?

Comment: Nothing but some QML object identifier? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html "The ID attribute".

Comment: @AlexanderV yes, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that viewRoot is the value of the id property of object. See [QML docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html).

**Id** - This is a unique identifier of the object, which can be used to access the properties of the object.

Example :

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Column {
    width: 200; height: 200

    TextInput { id: myTextInput; text: "Hello World" } // create object of TextInput type and myTextInput id.

    Text { text: myTextInput.text } // get value of text property from myTextInput
}
```

Create the qml object in c++

```cpp
QQmlEngine engine;
QQmlComponent component(&engine,
        QUrl::fromLocalFile("MyItem.qml"));
QObject *object = component.create();
```

And set property

```cpp
object->setProperty("width", 500);
```

See [qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html)